# Prolog - How To Make Prolog Query Shorter?

Tags: syntax, prolog, swi-prolog

I've been trying to learn Prolog and this particular thing has been bugging me for a while: to get anything done, my query need to be shockingly long. In particular, I have the following snippet that represents a simple classification program:

```
% Define the objects
object(pencil, stationery).
object(apple, organic).
object(eraser, stationery).
object(book, stationery).
object(mouse, electronic).
object(mp3, electronic).
object(ipad, electronic).

% Define the baskets
basket(red_basket, electronic).
basket(tall_basket, stationery).
basket(round_basket, organic).

% Define the sorting rule
sort_object(Object, Basket) :-
    object(Object, Type),
    basket(Basket, Type).

% Query the program to sort the objects into the baskets
% How can we reduce this last statement to be MUCH shorter?
?- sort_object(pencil, Basket1), sort_object(apple, Basket2), sort_object(eraser, Basket3), sort_object(book, Basket4), sort_object(mouse, Basket5), sort_object(mp3, Basket6), sort_object(ipad, Basket7).
```

I like it that all the term definitions are as succinct as they can be, but the final query is WAYYYYYYY TOOOO LONG to my liking and feels wrong. In contrary, if we were to implement the same thing in Elixir, one might do:

```
defmodule DB do
  def objects do
    [:pencil, :iPad, :basketball, :laptop, :apple]
  end
end

defmodule ObjectHelper do
  def get_type(:pencil), do: :stationery
  def get_type(:iPad), do: :electronics
  def get_type(:basketball), do: :sport
  def get_type(:laptop), do: :electronics
  def get_type(:apple), do: :food
end

defmodule BasketHelper do
  def get_basket(:electronics), do: :red
  def get_basket(:stationery), do: :yellow
  def get_basket(_), do: :blue
end

DB.objects
|> Enum.group_by(fn o -> o |> ObjectHelper.get_type |> BasketHelper.get_basket end)
|> IO.inspect
```

The goal is to output the correct baskets for each object, and you can envision doing that easily in C++ or Python cleanly albeit with longer code.

My question is:

1. Is there any construct to allow a more succinct query?
2. If there anything "wrong" with my question - maybe for achieving this task in practice, there are better ways to formulate the problem?

I am using SWI Prolog.
Thanks!

Comment: You could define a predicate that takes a list of objects and creates/"returns" a list of the associated baskets, basically doing `sort_object` on each element of the list, which is basically what you are doing in Elixr.

Comment: Ask `?- sort_object(O,B).` (and press ';' to see each possible answer) , `?- forall(sort_object(O,B), writeln(O->B)).` (to see all possible answers at once), or `?- findall(O-B, sort_object(O,B), L).` (to collect all answers in a list L).

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for the reply. Can you please show an example? A bit hard to comprehend how.

Comment: @ScottHunter As to processing as a list, can you also please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78148303/prolog-what-to-do-with-csv-files I feel the solutions might be similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is `findall/3` (or `bagof/3`) to find all solutions to a goal and gather up the results according to a template. For this, an Object and a Basket are a pair of things and a common way to pair two things in Prolog is `A-B`, a term of two things joined with a hyphen:

```
?- findall(O-B, sort_object(O, B), Pairs).

Pairs = [pencil-tall_basket, apple-round_basket, eraser-tall_basket, 
         book-tall_basket, mouse-red_basket, mp3-red_basket, ipad-red_basket]
```

Second option is a less pure 'failure driven loop' to search, print the result, then fail the search and trigger backtracking to retry the search:

```
?- sort_object(O, B),
   format('Thing: ~w, Basket: ~w,~n', [O,B]),
   false.

Thing: pencil. Basket: tall_basket.
Thing: apple. Basket: round_basket.
Thing: eraser. Basket: tall_basket.
Thing: book. Basket: tall_basket.
Thing: mouse. Basket: red_basket.
Thing: mp3. Basket: red_basket.
Thing: ipad. Basket: red_basket.
false
```

but that doesn't give you the items to work with in your program.

Third option if you want the items grouped, SWI Prolog has `group_by/4` which finds the groups on backtracking:

```
?- group_by(B, O, sort_object(O, B), Items).

B = red_basket,
Items = [mouse, mp3, ipad] ;

B = round_basket,
Items = [apple] ;

B = tall_basket,
Items = [pencil, eraser, book]
```

and that can be wrapped in findall as well:

```
?- findall(B-Items,
        group_by(B, O, sort_object(O, B), Items),
        AllGroups).

AllGroups = [red_basket-[mouse, mp3, ipad],
             round_basket-[apple],
             tall_basket-[pencil, eraser, book]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, rename `sort_object` to a relation-based name, rather than an action name, as more fitting for this bi-directional lookup (especially since there is no [sort](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) involved):

```
object_basket(Object, Basket) :-
    object(Object, Type),
    basket(Basket, Type).
```

Then, can use [maplist](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3):

```
?- Objects = [pencil, apple, eraser, book, mouse, mp3, ipad],
   maplist(object_basket, Objects, Baskets).
Objects = [pencil, apple, eraser, book, mouse, mp3, ipad],
Baskets = [tall_basket, round_basket, tall_basket, tall_basket, red_basket, red_basket, red_basket].
```

Comment: Very elegant indeed! This answer is very succinct but I have picked @TessellatingHeckler because it's more comprehensive.