# Prolog - How to Convert CSV File Output Rows into Queryable Terms?

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to learn to use Prolog and was very pleasantly surprised to find SWI Prolog provides a CSV library out of the box: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv

However I have no idea how to use it, specifically, with below data (saved inside `Data.csv` file):

```
Name,Value
A,150
B,300
C,50
```

And below snippet:

```
:- use_module(library(csv)).

get_data(Rows) :-
    csv_read_file("Data.csv", Rows).
```

I could in swipl easily get the following:

```bash
> swipl .\Code.pl
1 ?- get_data(Rows).
Rows = [row('Name', 'Value'), row('A', 150), row('B', 300), row('C', 50)].
```

However, the return result looks like a list of terms, and there are two issues:

1. How do I skip the first header row? I tried to look at documentation and couldn't figure out an easy way. ChatGPT says I might need to use `csv_read_stream` instead? Can you please show an example?
2. What do I do with `Rows`? What I would like to do is to interactively make queries in swipl just as with raw prolog terms/predicates loaded as a `.pl` file. E.g. I wish to issue queries like this: `?- row(Name,Value), Value > 150.` to find all names with `Value` above a certain value.

Thanks!

Remark:

- [Import csv file data to populate a Prolog knowledge base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095068/import-csv-file-data-to-populate-a-prolog-knowledge-base) Partly answers my question but it says "see it at documentation" which I tried and couldn't comprehend - I need specific code examples on how to ignore the first header row and how to make use of the returned list as queryable knowledge.

Comment: Can anyone please elaborate why they vote down. I find StackOverflow quite hostile to my questions which I always tried my best to ask only good questions and as a very experienced programmer I don't ask dumb questions without trying.

Comment: To skip the header row: `Rows = [Head|Tail].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the tail part of the list, you can pattern match in the query itself.

```
get_data([Header|Rows]).
```

Now with the `Rows` you have, you need to check for `member`s of the list.

```
?- member(X, [1, 2, 3, 4]), X >= 3.
X = 3 ;
X = 4.
```

so full query would be something like:

```
get_data([Header|Rows]), member(row(Name, Value), Rows), Value > 50.
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!
How do you use something like `findall()` to gather all such rows as a single filtered list? I can't figure out the right syntax for that.

Comment: I figured one could write a new predicate: `filter(Row, Rows) :- Row = row(_, Value), member(Row, Rows), Value > 50.` then do `?- get_data([_|Rows]), findall(F, filter(F, Rows), Bag).` - is there a way to write it such that we don't need to define that new predicate, i.e. write it in a single line?

Comment: I asked above question in a dedicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149722/prolog-filtering-list-using-findall-with-in-line-predicate-or-lambda